# How can I do this in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I need a little of help on my homework, i have to make an array in haskell where through the pointers "i" and "j" i have to find two numbers where the result is the number that the user write.
For example:

User writes the number 7, so the program has to go through every number comparing in two sides (pointers "i" and "j"; "i" goes from start to right and "j" goes from the end to the left) if the result of the sum is the same as the user input.
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

I don't know if i'm explaining myself, I hope you can help me guys.
For example "i" is on position 1 and "j" is on position 4.
i = 2
j = 5   so "i" + "j" = 7

then I have to print the position where it found "I" and "j".

Comment: Sounds like you might have some C background. Try to reimagine the question: what you really need is to find the sum of all *pairs* of numbers from the list. If you can create that list of pairs, then it's easy to find the ones that sum to the target.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sound like [(x,y) | x <- [1..7], y <- [1..7], x+y==7]

Comment: You can just use `[(x, 7-x) | x <- [1..7]]` here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I too interpreted it this way at first, but their example seems to suggest the Cartesian product, not the zippery pairing up of the elements.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: The task you have before you is to remove the procedural paradigm from your thought process, so that the functional paradigm can replace it as you learn it. You'll be able to re-integrate both one day. But for now, thinking in procedural terms won't help you at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to code with list comprehensions:

```
findIt :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [(Int, Int)]
findIt xs it = [ (i,j) | (j,y) <- reverse $ zip [0..] xs, 
                         (i,x) <- zip [0..] xs, 
                         i<=j, x+y == it ]

GHCi> findIt [1..10] 18
[(7,9),(8,8)]
```

The above code is of course quadratic in the number of entries in the list.

Coding this efficiently is an interesting algorithmic question.